# Setting a priority on a function so it will not be overwritten

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a wordpress site that has all of its meta info set dynamically by a plugin. What I am trying to do is setup a function to set specific meta info by using a switch. Is there a priority I can set on the function so that it does not get overwritten by the plugin?

Comment: Why not overwrite the plugin's function?

Comment: well the problem is I am optimizing only a few pages and want to let the plugin create the meta info for the pages I am not editing.

Comment: what about declaring the function protected?

Comment: that might be the way to go but I was also looking into setting the function with final

Comment: Can you post the relevant code parts?